# SQLCMD Passing in Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, ssms, sqlcmd

I have a batch file which runs a number of `*.sql` files. Currently all the variables have been hard coded within the `sql` files. I wanted to know how to pass in variables values from the `SQLCMD` Batch File.

Example of Variable names:

> ```
> DECLARE @TW_FROM DATETIME
> DECLARE @TW_TO DATETIME
> SET @TW_FROM = '2015-11-16 00:00:00';
> SET @TW_TO = '2015-11-16 00:00:00';
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the -v option to set a scripting variable that exists in a script. In the following script (the file name is testscript.sql), ColumnName is a scripting variable.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
SELECT x.$(ColumnName)
FROM Person.Person x
WHERE c.BusinessEntityID < 5;
```

You can then specify the name of the column that you want returned by using the -v option:

```
sqlcmd -v ColumnName ="FirstName" -i c:\testscript.sql
```

To return a different column by using the same script, change the value of the ColumnName scripting variable.

```
sqlcmd -v ColumnName ="LastName" -i c:\testscript.sql
```

More documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have explained, I'm quite new to SQL. Could you please give me some guidance to declaring these variables in both SQL and *.bat file? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: CallSqlScript.cmd

sqlcmd -S %1 -i select.sql -v dbname = %2 tablename = %3
We will call this batch file something like this:

CallSqlScript.cmd Parameter1 Parameter2 Parameter3

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssehgal/archive/2009/04/03/passing-parameters-to-sql-script-using-batch-files.aspx

Comment: I manage to get this working!! Yes! Finally, how can I set global variables in the *.bat file? 

e.g. 

SET TW_FROM = "xx/xx/xx"

SET TW_TO = "xx/xx/xx"

Then pass in TW_FROM and TW_TO into the sqlcmd line

Comment: I would be super happy if you could set the original question to answered if you appreciate me spending time to help you, that would motivate me more to answer your follow up questions.